# Angularjs: TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please find the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/UxYLa/6/

This is a simplified form of what I am trying to do. There are two directive, and the nested one, `subDirective`, which dynamically creates html form based on the selection(random). If you click repeatedly on the button, it throws below error

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js:138:283
    at q (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js:7:332)
    at q.after (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js:138:258)
    at Object.O.(anonymous function) [as after] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js:139:414)
    at Object.enter (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js:141:226)
    at Object.move (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js:141:360)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js:185:282
    at Object.fn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js:99:371)
```

I found a reference about this
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/dNra_7P2hwU/09-UBn1XxyUJ
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2151 but I am using the latest stable version.

What is the cause of this error.

Full code below:

### script:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('TestController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.data = [{ type: "a", values: [{name:"aa"}, {name: "bb"}]},
          { type: "b", values: [{name:"aa"}, {name: "bb"}]}]
}]);   
myApp.directive('directive', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            data: "=",
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.random = function(){
                $scope.model = $scope.data[Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.data.length)];
                console.log($scope.model)
            };
        },
         template: '<div><button ng-click="random()">Random</button><sub-directive data="model"></sub-directive></div>'
    };
});


myApp.directive('subDirective', function ($templateCache, $compile) {
    return {    
         scope: {
            data: "=",
        },
        restrict: 'E', 
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
             scope.$watch('data', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal) {
                     element.html($templateCache.get(newVal.type + '.html'));
                     $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                 }
             });
        }
    };
});
```

### html

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="a.html">
     a.html
  </script>


<script type="text/ng-template" id="b.html">
      <div ng-repeat="itm in data">
          <span ng-if='"string" == itm.type'>
              <input name='{{itm.Name}}'id='{{itm.Name}}' ng-model='model[itm.Name]' type='text'></input>
          </span>
      </div>
  </script>

<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <directive data="data"></directive>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has something to do with the compilation and how data is bound. I made a working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/UxYLa/9/

The main differences are in b.html

```
  <div ng-if="data.values">
      <div ng-repeat="itm in data.values">
          <input name='{{itm.name}}' id='{{itm.name}}' ng-model="itm.name" type='text'></input>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Have to interate over arrays and refer to itm instead of model since it's in the scope.

Edit: after some digging here are some more clues as to why the error happens, but not when you wrap it in a div. It is calling this: `parent.insertBefore(node, index.nextSibling);` where parent is element.parent of your ng-repeat. If you don't have the wrapper, the parent is null.

This means the error occurs whenever the html you are compiling has a watch that is on the outside of the template when directly changing the element.

I also made a solution that doesn't attempt to change element directly, but rather appends the compiled element to it. So that everything, when it's checked in the digest cycle will have a proper structure. http://jsfiddle.net/UxYLa/12/

Hope this helped.

Comment: +1 thank you very much. If I remove `<div ng-if="data.values">
` from your code, it breaks. No idea how to explain this. Not sure how reliably I can use this way. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: What I think is happening is that the html changes to a.html, but the watches in b.html are still trying to update when you compile a. Which has some errors. Atleast, it appears to have something to do with that. It may help to include angular.js instead of angular.min.js as well.

Comment: thanks again. At least I could narrow down bit further. Having ng-repeat at the root of the template was the cause. Wrapping it in a div seems to stop the error. see http://jsfiddle.net/UxYLa/10/ . Would love to understand why?

Comment: I added a few more details, it's starting to make a little sense?

Comment: I could access the previous version of your fiddle (not 12). Is http://jsfiddle.net/UxYLa/11/ is the final sol you were referring. Anyway, thanks for the explanation and have some idea now. Will update once you confirm.

Comment: Oh weird, try it now. I was just updating the ng-model to be correct from 11->12.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same error message. I could fix this by **referencing JQuery before Angular** in my html script tags.

Comment: Great idea, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but I found I was adding `class="md-sticky"` on a `<md-subheader>` tag, and it meant to say `class="md-no-sticky"`

As soon as I changed this class, that sorted the problem for me, but I also had the same issue with using an `ng-repeat` not within it's own parent tag, but I had! It was just I used `ng-show="condition"` on that parent tag, and if that parent tag didn't show it would cause this issue, so I changed it to `ng-if="condition"` and that sorted that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and what seemed to solve it was removing a class of "ng-view" that I had on one of my divs. It's like it was causing a conflict.

I had:

```
<div class="ng-view"> 
  <div ng-view>
    ...
```

Then changed to:

```
<div class="ngview">
  <div ng-view>
    ...
```

I'm guessing ng-view is a reserved word, but I didn't think it would be affected when used as a class.

Comment: ng-view is an angular-route directive

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using UI-Router and the A tag had the wrong URL in the href attribute which was not a route.