# ng-repeat returns TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object array called $scope.transactions = [....] and it has proper values. but when I access it inside ng-repeat as below it returns the above
error.

**controller code**:

```
application.controller("custTransactionCtrl", function($scope, StbetServices) {
    $scope.transactions=[];
    .....
    .......
     $.ajax({
            url: 'CustomerTransaction',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                fromDate: fromDate,
                toDate: toDate,
                type:$scope.selectedItem.id
            },
            success: function(data1) {
                 $scope.transactions = JSON.parse(data1);

            },
            error: function(jqXHR) {
                console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
```

and I use this **transactions** array inside my html as below:

**My HTML**:

```
         <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="t in transactions">
                    <td align="left">{{t.transactionDescription}}</td>
                    <td align="left">{{t.transactionDate}} </td>
                    <td align="left">{{t.transactionAmount}}</td>
                    <td align="left">{{t.customerAccount.id}}</td>
                    <td align="left">{{t.transactionReference}}</td>
                    <td align="left">{{t.transactionReference2}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

this will return `****TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null****` and the complete error message is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null
    at http://192.168.1.222:8080/stbet/lib/angular.js:2247:13
    at forEach (http://192.168.1.222:8080/stbet/lib/angular.js:133:18)
    at forEach.after (http://192.168.1.222:8080/stbet/lib/angular.js:2246:5)
    at Object.JQLite.(anonymous function) [as after] (http://192.168.1.222:8080/stbet/lib/angular.js:2301:17)
    at http://192.168.1.222:8080/stbet/lib/angular.js:14038:22
    at publicLinkFn (http://192.168.1.222:8080/stbet/lib/angular.js:4095:29)
    at Object.ngRepeatWatch (http://192.168.1.222:8080/stbet/lib/angular.js:14037:13)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$digest (http://192.168.1.222:8080/stbet/lib/angular.js:8090:47)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$apply (http://192.168.1.222:8080/stbet/lib/angular.js:8304:24)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://192.168.1.222:8080/stbet/lib/angular.js:13255:17)
```

**UPDATED:**

please find the console output below:

[image]

Comment: $scope.transactions = data1;

Comment: nope @DmitriAlgazin , that is not the issue here.

Comment: Show full controller code, is your `transactions` property initialized before ajax call? Like `$scope.transactions = []`

Comment: yes @Andrey, it is initialized as it is!

Comment: @Nomesh DeSilva, then we need to ensure, that JSON.parse returns Array. Please see related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419368/angularjs-typeerror-cannot-call-method-insertbefore-of-null

Comment: Just curious, why don't you use $http instead of ajax from jQuery?

Comment: @Andrey when I put "console.log(typeof($scope.transactions));" it returns "object"..is there any issue with it..?

Comment: show the output of returned result:  success: function(data1){console.log("data", data1);}

Answer (score 1):

It's because Angular compilation and how data is bound. You must add `ng-if="transactions"` in `tbody` attributes like this :

```
<tbody ng-if="transactions">
    <tr ng-repeat="t in transactions">
        <td align="left">{{t.transactionDescription}}</td>
        <td align="left">{{t.transactionDate}} </td>
        <td align="left">{{t.transactionAmount}}</td>
        <td align="left">{{t.customerAccount.id}}</td>
        <td align="left">{{t.transactionReference}}</td>
        <td align="left">{{t.transactionReference2}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Tanks to hassassin for his help. More information here : [Angularjs: TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419368/angularjs-typeerror-cannot-call-method-insertbefore-of-null)